# How to replace the remote old root partition?

Tags: root, restore, remote

please help.
On the remote server the system got hacked. I want to replace the whole root partition with a new one. I want to create a root image locally and copy and mount it to the remote system under mnt. I need to tell the system, where to find the new root partition and umount the old root drive. How can I carry out that?

Thanks,
István

Comment: Check out `man fstab` from a terminal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your /etc/fstab is going to have an entry like this:

> UUID=5533a862-a975-4a4e-ad8e-31327966c028 /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1

or like this:

> /dev/sda3 /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1

You need to make the /etc/fstab entry point to either the new device file our the disk's UUID

Before changing the fstab, mount it as a disk owned by root and verify you can see the files:
add to fstab where the /dev file points to new disk and just after the root mount shown above:

```
/dev/sda3   /newroot    ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
sudo mkdir /newroot
sudo mount -a
```

If it mounts, then verify root can read/write files okay in /newroot

If that works, edit /etc/fstab to put a # in front of existing root and change new line you added to be / instead of /newroot then reboot. Note, you'll have to use a LiveCD to set it back or edit the fstab if it fails to boot properly

Comment: You will have to update grub as well ;)

Comment: Down-voting this as it will not work without updating grub as well

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks. Let me see if I understand correctly.  So I mount the new (root) partition, I set as a root partition, I comment out the old one, and I need to run the grub update command. Sounds simply. My risk is big, because it is a remote system. May be I need to test this method in a virtual environment first.